# Get a boolean value from a shorthand conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Shorthand Javascript is great but I am wondering if it is possible to take this shorthand conditional one step further to giving a true / false value depending on whether the condition passed or not. E.g. Take this:

```
$('#col-URL-defaultText').css('display', ((val!==null && val!=="") ? 'none' : 'block'));
```

and create something like this:

```
var empty = $('#col-URL-defaultText').css('display', ((val!==null && val!=="") ? 'none' : 'block'));
```

(^ The above fails but hopefully you get what I am trying to achieve ^)

Comment: `Boolean empty` ? javascript does not have that kind of types

Comment: Maybe you want this? `var empty = (val!==null && val!=="")`

Comment: In your `empty` variable would be the return value of the `.css()` function, which is a jQuery object

Comment: `var empty = !$('#col-URL-defaultText').toggle(!!val).is(':visible')`

Comment: How is what you're doing at the top different than what you want to do at the bottom, other than assigning to a variable, like @haim770 said?

Comment: @Pablo I put 'Boolean' because it makes it more obvious to what I want to achieve, I already know the line doesn't work so why change it to var

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a way of assigning a boolean while also checking the display properties on a *single* line. @codemonkey65 gave the only correct answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, by testing what the resulting display attribute is and assigning it to a variable:

```
Boolean empty = $('#col-URL-defaultText').css('display', ((val!==null && val!=="") ? 'none' : 'block')).css('display')=='block';
```

I'm not sure if you actually want to test against 'block' or 'none' at the end.

Comment: Thanks for a correct way of doing this. I used 'var' instead of 'Boolean' for it to work but you managed to answer my actual question instead of shouting at me for wanting to put it all onto one line.

Comment: What is wrong with wanting to know if something will work? A load of these 'developers' need to get their head out their arse and try alternative solutions like yours rather than believing their ways are always correct

Answer (score 3):

Assign result to variable and use it after it:

```
var notEmpty = (val !== null && val !== '');
$(....).css('display', notEmpty ? "none" : "block");
```

Comment: because less lines is not equal to more quality.+1

Comment: Thanks for another solution. I get that this will work but it just completely ignored the original question. I wanted to KNOW if there was a one line solution, @Brian not a snobby philosophical comment

Comment: @JonathanHill it's not snobby at all, i'm dead serious. your code will not be better just for doing stuff on one line, it will actually be worse, because you probably won't know what it does whenever you need to revisit the project a month down... Also, if you really want one line, just delete the line break.

Comment: well, can't edit for some reason, so sorry for another comment: btw, these two lines are shorter than the accepted answer when put on one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make everything into a single line, you could abuse the syntax by wrapping everything inside an anonymous function:

```
var notEmpty = (function(b){ $(....).css('display', b ? "none" : "block"); return b })(val !== null && val !== '');
```

But, frankly, I would prefer [oryol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41123886/679240); it's way more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using function  .css('display', ...)
You  can use hide and show functions, it's more easy to maintain in my opinion.

```
var $this = $('#col-URL-defaultText');
var empty = val !== undefined ?  $this.show() : $this.hide();
```